# Focus does not hide the hint on browser back button (jquery.hint.js)

Tags: javascript, back-button

I use jquery.hint.js. On page load everiting is fine but when i use back browser button the focus does not hide the hint.

```
jQuery.fn.hint = function (blurClass) {
    if (!blurClass) {
        blurClass = 'blur';
    }

    return this.each(function () {
        // get jQuery version of 'this'
        var $input = jQuery(this),

        // capture the rest of the variable to allow for reuse
          title = $input.attr('title'),
          $form = jQuery(this.form),
          $win = jQuery(window);

        function remove() {
            if ($input.val() === title && $input.hasClass(blurClass)) {
                $input.val('').removeClass(blurClass);
            }
        }

        // only apply logic if the element has the attribute
        if (title) {
            // on blur, set value to title attr if text is blank
            $input.blur(function () {
                if (this.value === '') {
                    $input.val(title).addClass(blurClass);
                }
            }).focus(remove).blur(); // now change all inputs to title

            // clear the pre-defined text when form is submitted
            $form.submit(remove);
            $win.unload(remove); // handles Firefox's autocomplete
        }
    });
};
```

example on normal page load: http://prntscr.com/sik0d
example after using back browser button: http://prntscr.com/sikap (doses not hide the hint on focus, it just add text to input field)

how to fix this. How to force this script to reload on back button? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find jquery.hint.js witch includes a fix for using the browser back button. So here is a link: https://gist.github.com/madmanlear/1723896

JavaScript:

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.hint = function (blurClass) {
    if (!blurClass) blurClass = 'blur';

    return this.each(function () {
        var $input = $(this),
            title = $input.attr('placeholder'),
            $form = $(this.form),
            $win = $(window);

        function remove() {
            if ($input.val() === title) {
                $input.val('').removeClass(blurClass);
            }
        }

        // only apply logic if the element has the attribute
        if (title) { 
            // on blur, set value to title attr if text is blank

            $input.blur(function () {
                if (this.value === '' || this.value == title) {
                    $input.val(title).addClass(blurClass);
                }
            }).focus(remove).blur(); // now change all inputs to title

            // clear the pre-defined text when form is submitted
            $form.submit(remove);
            $win.unload(remove); // handles Firefox's autocomplete
        }
    });
};

})(jQuery);
```